# Maven clean install in CircleCI

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, cicd, circleci

I am trying CircleCI to set build pipeline for my maven project.
The intent is to run `mvn clean install -s settings.xml`

my config.yml looks like following

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  maven: circleci/maven@1.4.1
  slack: circleci/slack@4.4.4
  docker: circleci/docker@2.2.0

workflows:
  maven:
    jobs:
      - maven/test:
          maven_command: mvn
          command: clean install
          settings_file: settings.xml
          verify_dependencies: false
```

But it is failing because of wrong target version 17

```
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 334 source files to /home/circleci/project/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  04:30 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-07-19T00:11:16Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project *****: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 17 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

What should I change into my config to use java17?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the project expects JDK 17, which isn't available in the executor.

As per the [docs in the maven orb for CircleCI](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/maven), you can pass in an executor which can specify JDK version, you should specify JDK 17.

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  maven: circleci/maven@1.4.1
  slack: circleci/slack@4.4.4
  docker: circleci/docker@2.2.0

workflows:
  maven:
    jobs:
      - maven/test:
          executor: 
            name: maven/default
            tag: '17.0'
          maven_command: mvn
          command: clean install
          settings_file: settings.xml
          verify_dependencies: false
```

Where the maven/default executor is the cimg/openjdj convenience Docker image, with these available tags: https://circleci.com/developer/images/image/cimg/openjdk

Hope this helps!

Comment: it shows following lint errors:
```
Error calling workflow: 'maven'
Error calling job: 'maven/test'
Unexpected executor invocation format
The value of `name` must be a string
Examples of correct executor invocation:
  executor: string-executor-name
  executor: {name: string-executor-name}
  executor: << parameters.executor-type-parameter >>

```

Comment: I believe the original config around executor definition was wrong - I updated it now so it should work